# git branch -a lists merged/deleted branches

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

Whenever I write the command `git branch -a` to see all my branches locally and remotely I somehow see old branches that have been merged in and closed. How do I get rid of these branches that no longer exist in my local git or github?

Answer (score 13):

If `git branch -a` shows them, they exist locally.  That's what `git branch` lists: things that exist locally.

Your Git's branches are *yours*.  They are not some other Git's.

Your Git's *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/master`, are *also* yours, but your Git will automatically synchronize them with what it sees on the other Git over at `origin`.  That is, if the other Git has a branch named `feature/tall`, your Git will create or update your `origin/feature/tall` when you connect your Git to their Git and have your Git obtain new stuff from them.

You can have your Git automatically *delete* remote-tracking names as well.  This is not the default—if your Git saw their `feature/tall` last week, and therefore created your `origin/feature/tall`, and yesterday they deleted *their* `feature/tall`, your Git will continue to retain your `origin/feature/tall` by default.  To tell your Git: *If they've deleted theirs, delete my remote-tracking name that copies theirs*, you have several options:

- Run `git fetch origin --prune`: this calls up the Git at `origin`, gets their list of branches, and figures out which `origin/*` names to remove, while also updating `origin`.
- Run `git remote prune`: this calls up *all* Gits at *all* of your remotes.  (Well, it's very configurable, but that's the default.)  If you only have one remote, named `origin`, that has the same effect.
- Configure `fetch.prune` to `true`:

  ```
  git config fetch.prune true
  ```

  Now all `git fetch` operations will act like you used `--prune`.

Your *branches*, being yours, are yours to create and delete at will.  If you don't want branch `feature/short` any more, delete it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they still exist in the remote-tracking part of your local repository (if the name looks like `refs/remote/origin/branchname`). You can delete all remote-tracking branches which don't exist anymore on the remote repository with the command `git fetch --prune`. That command will not touch any of your local branches.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -d <YOUR-BRANCH-NAME>`

if you have merged all changes from a branch

or

`git branch -D <YOUR-BRANCH-NAME>`

if you have unmerged changes on the branch that you want to delete.

`-D` acts as a force delete